# Connection to the same database in another computer with ado.net

Tags: c#, sql

I've made a c# app in my host computer and it all works. I read the username and the password i previously created on SQL through c# and the connection suceeds. Now I decided to test it on a VM with VMWARE, windows 10 VM. Installed SSMS, created the Database, executed all querys, and the user as i did on my host computer but now the connection always fails. Here is the connection string I use on the code:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Initial Catalog={database_name};UID=" + user + ";password=" + pw;
```

Any ideas on why it connects on host but not on other computers? I've also tried in a friends pc and connection still fails!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You don't define the `Server`/ `Data Source`, how do you expect it to find it?

Comment: That was exactly the issue, i never defined it because on my host machine it worked without it. Now after telling it what server it was it worked like a charm, thank you